# ES6 - exporting named export without importing them?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's assume I have a folder with two files called `ModuleA.js` and `ModuleB.js` that looks like this:

**ModuleA.js**

```
export default {
  someKey: 'Hello, world',
};
```

**ModuleB.js**

```
export const foo = 'bar';
export const another = 'variable';
```

Then I have an `index.js` file that I would like to perform named export on those modules without writing the `import` statement. I know how to do it with `ModuleA`:

```
export { default as ModuleA } from './ModuleA';
```

But how can I import the name exports and export them in one line without writing e.g.?

```
import * as _ModuleB from './ModuleB'
export const ModuleB = _ModuleB;
```

Comment: You can `import * as ModuleB from '…'` and `export { ModuleB }`, you don't need a local `const` variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only reexport everything:

```
 export * from "./ModuleB";
```

But you can't group that under a new namespace without importing & exporting. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from) to change that.